# Last column background color inside 100% width section

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building the website and I want to reach the section like on my psd (img attached):
[image]

You can see that there's 100% width section and `.col-md-9` and `.col-md-3` inside this section. 
But when .col-md-3 ends its background should continue and pave the background of the main section.

How can I make the column's background continue? I've spent hours solving this problem but I didn't find the correct way. Thanks!

```css
.single__content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 743px;
    padding-top: 57px;
}
.single__content p {
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 23px;
}
.single__meta {
    background: #3c73ba;
    height: 70px;
}
.single__meta h2 {
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 42px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 14px;
}
.col-sidebar {
    background: #4285db;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="single__meta">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-md-9">
              <h2 class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sidebar col-md-3">
              Second column content
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the background of your top with `background: linear-gradient`.

[Demo with bootstrap 4](https://www.codeply.com/go/5FcCkyTXqo)

```css
.top-bar {
    background: linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    #3c73ba 0%, 
    #3c73ba 50%, 
    #4285db 50%, 
    #4285db 100%
  );
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.col-left{
    background: #3c73ba;
}
.col-right {
    background: #4285db;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar" style="padding: 0">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-left col-md-9">
              <h2>left</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-right col-md-3">
              <h2>right</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      "make  this changes in your code" hope this u want


   <div class="row col_bg">
           <div class="col-md-9 ">
              <h2 class="page-title">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sidebar col-md-3">
              Second column content
          </div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
    </div>

   "for css"


.row.col_bg {
  background-color: #4285db;
  clear: both;
}

.col-md-9 {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  }

 .single__meta h2 {
   color: #000;
   font-size: 38px;
   font-weight: 300;
   line-height: 42px;
    margin: 0;
 }


 .col-sidebar.col-md-3 {
   float: right;
    width: 30%;
   }

 .clear {
     clear: both;
       }
```